# Where in Python can I find real_fft() these days? It's not in numpy.fft

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I have some ancient code (5 years old) and how I used to access real_fft() method was this:

```
from FFT import *
real_fft(data, fft_length)
```

I guess the FFT module came with NumPy. Now, years later I installed the NumPy 1.6.1 with

```
pip install numpy
```

And all I see in the docs http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Functions_by_Category, are these functions:

fft()

fftfreq()

fftshift()

ifft()

It is strange, because in this numpy docs, real_fft() is there:

http://numpy.sourceforge.net/numdoc/HTML/numdoc.htm#pgfId-304711

Comment: I would guess the ones you're seeing on the SciPy docs are the ones available in the scipy namespace, while the other list is those available in the numpy namespace.

Comment: Import the FFT module, then do `dir(FFT)` to find the available functions. Maybe there's something interesting there.

Comment: Thanks for good tips, but I think I found a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like NumPy underwent some reorganisation in recent years.

http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc#fft

FFT is now numpy.fft, and real_fft() seems to be renamed into rfft()

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> 
>>> signal = array([-2.,  8., -6.,  4.,  1., 0.,  3.,  5.]) 
>
>>> from numpy.fft import *
>>> 
>>> 
>>> f = fft(signal)
>>> 
>>> 
>>> print f
[ 13.00000000 +0.j           3.36396103 +4.05025253j   2.00000000 +1.j
  -9.36396103-13.94974747j -21.00000000 +0.j          -9.36396103+13.94974747j
   2.00000000 -1.j           3.36396103 -4.05025253j]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> f = rfft(signal)
>>> 
>>> print f
[ 13.00000000 +0.j           3.36396103 +4.05025253j   2.00000000 +1.j
  -9.36396103-13.94974747j -21.00000000 +0.j        ]
>>> 
>>>
```